# Firestore DocumentSnapshot to Python dictionary

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I've been going around in circles trying to get my Firestore data into a Python 2 dictionary.

```
    doc_ref = db.collection('things1').document('ref1').collection('things2').document('ref2')
    doc = doc_ref.get()
```

gets me a DocumentSnapshot  - I was hoping to get a dict.  What's the proper way to create a dict from the results.  Tried the docs and just end up with the object.  Something dumb I'm (not) doing.

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

You could use [`to_dict()`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/firestore/document.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1beta1.document.DocumentSnapshot.to_dict), this should give you the dictionary of the result.

```py
doc_ref = db.collection('things1').document('ref1').collection('things2').document('ref2') 
doc = doc_ref.get().to_dict()
```

Comment: why was this suddenly not the correct answer? @Townheadbluesboy?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
doc = {el.id: el.to_dict() for el in doc_ref}
```