# Querying an array of references

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array that contains a bunch of references to users. I'm trying to find all of the games that my user is in. It seems like it should be pretty straightforward to do this. The `Game` collection contains an array Players, with the references to the user.

```
def list_games(user):
    return db.collection(u'Game').where("Players","array_contains",user)

for row in db.collection(u'User').get():
    user=row
list_games(user)
```

When I try this simple code, I'm getting an error on the line in list_games that is included below. (Removed some path information, but otherwise intact)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "listGames.py", line 29, in <module>
    for game in list_games(user).get():
  File "listGames.py", line 14, in list_games
    return db.collection(u'Game').where("Players","array_contains",user)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\firestore_v1beta1\collection.py", line 222, in where
    return query.where(field_path, op_string, value)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\firestore_v1beta1\query.py", line 265, in where
    value=_helpers.encode_value(value),
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-pakages\google\cloud\firestore_v1beta1\_helpers.py", line 200, in encode_value
    "Cannot convert to a Firestore Value", value, "Invalid type", type(value)
TypeError: ('Cannot convert to a Firestore Value', <google.cloud.firestore_v1beta1.document.DocumentSnapshot object at 0x000000000454D668>, 'Invalid type', <class 'google.cloud.firestore_v1beta1.document.DocumentSnapshot'>)
```

It seems to me I should do something different for the user, something like `user.id`, but I can't figure it out. What do I need to do to get search the array for references? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`user` is a [DocumentSnapshot](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/firestore/document.html), so you should be dealing with it as such.  Perhaps you want to [convert it to a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49077425/firestore-documentsnapshot-to-python-dictionary) with `to_dict()`.

Comment: This ran, but it did not give anything as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing to do is to compare the `.reference`, as shown below.

```
def list_games(user):
    return db.collection(u'Game').where("Players","array_contains",user.reference)
```